# How to add a map scale to the map in AnyLogic

Tags: gis, anylogic

I am using GIS map in AnyLogic, the version of AnyLogic is 8.7.0, and the tile provider is AnyLogic.

Currently I dont have a map scale, but i have checked some tutorial, some of them seems like have a dynamic scale ruler by default, as I didn't see they make any related setting.

I was trying to add text block and use some funciton like getScale() to represent the scale, but it is not that good as a scale ruler.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you can't because when you zoom in/out of the map, the map doesn't return the result of that action, so anylogic doesn't know how zoomed in or zoomed out you are, so if you have an agent that represents the scale, you would be unable to update it properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Felipe. I have also noticed this problem, I can only use map.formatMapScale() to get a static scale, which will not change according to zoom in/out. So some old tutorials have the scale on their map, is that because of the different tile provider？

Comment: i don't know about that...